# DevExpress (DXv2) and DevArt dotConnect?

Tags: oracle, frameworks, devexpress, dotconnect

I'm writing a C# `Applications Solution v11.2` using `eXpressApp Framework` from **DevExpress** and the first thing I would like to do is make the 2 apps (web & win) connect to an `Oracle Database` without using the `Oracle Client`.

In my other projects I have used `DevArt's dotConnect` tool, which is great by the way (works without needing any Oracle Client installed).

I wonder if someone has tried this, 'cuz I just can't get it work. From what I read from the forums, I think that eXpress Framework doesn't recognize dotConnect's `OracleConnection`, or that I have to write my own XPO provider.. ?!

Please help!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

One of the approaches to accomplishing this task is to create a custom XPO connection provider. This class will be a descendant of one of the standard connection providers listed in the [Database Systems Supported by XPO](http://help.devexpress.com/#XPO/CustomDocument2114) help topic. I believe the [following KB article](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/ViewKBIssue.aspx?kbid=K18098) should helps.